# RSS Parsing in QML

Tags: xml, qt, symbian, nokia, qml

I wanna parse RSS feed with QML.

the feed structure looks like

```
<channel>
<item>
<title>
</title>
<description>
</description>
<media:content url="http://someURLHere.com/avatar/somethingHere?s=96&#38;d=identicon&#38;r=G" medium="image">
</media:content>
</item>
```

my problem is with the media:content tag, how can i parse the url with QML into a string ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't add a comment to coyotte508's answer, so here it is instead: you might need to add namespace for the 'media' using the XmlListModel's namespaceDeclarations property. An example:

```
XmlListModel {
  ...
  namespaceDeclarations: "declare namespace media = 'http://put/the/path/here';"
  XmlRole { name: "url"; query: "media:content/@url/string()" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-xmllistmodel.html and http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-xmlrole.html

Basically:

```
XmlModel {
  id: mymodel
  xml: "blabblabla" /* you can also use source: to read directly from the web */
  query: "/rss/channel/item/"

  XmlRole {
    name: "url"
    query: "media:content/@url/string()"
  }
}
```

And to retrieve it:

```
mymodel.get(0).url
```

If you have several channels and would like to retrieve the url for each, you can get the number of channels with mymodel.count, and access each of them with mymodel.get(i).

Comment: what i get is
QML XmlRole: invalid query: "media:content/@url/string()"

Comment: Then try media/@url/string(), @media/url/string(), @media:content/url/string(), or change XmlModel.query to "/rss/channel/item/media:content" and XmlRole.query to "@url/string()", and try without the ":content". See if one of those work.